# If any concerns let us know "or" If “there are” any concerns

Tags: british-english, email

We address people through email especially in the UK. Are there any grammatical issues in the sentences below?

> - If any concerns let us know
> - If **there are** any concerns let us know

Comment: Not as many grammatical issues as there are with that Question, anyway.

Would you mind taking the whole idea to English Language Learners?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second part is grammatical correct - If there are any concerns let us know.
Another common phrase is "Let me know if you have any questions or concerns"

Comment: Thanks @tyleman1209, If we use "If any concerns let us know" informal speech (and especially emails) is this still a major concern?

Comment: I would say "If you have any concerns let us know", this can be seen as both formal and informal.

Comment: Please assess the level of questions considered appropriate for ELU.

Answer (score 1):

Very similar question.
https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/88855/which-one-is-correct-to-use

A reasonable alternative might be,
"If you have any concerns let us know."